# Methodical and precise word guessing

Tags: riddle, word

I should begin by saying I am a word

In the beginning I followed established conventions

After that I decided that was not for me

So I decided to oppose everything that came after me

In the end I decided not to oppose, but to protect

covering, protecting and providing warmth

What word am I?

Answer (score 4):

So, I'm probably way off, but maybe at least part will spark something with someone else.

> Turncoat

I should begin by saying I am a word

> Update thanks to suggestion from Reticality. I am a word, one word. Turncoat is one word.

In the beginning I followed established conventions

> In the beginning a turncoat is a "good guy"

After that I decided that was not for me

> Decided to change sides.

So I decided to oppose everything that came after me

> Turning changes direction, possibly opposing?

In the end I decided not to oppose, but to protect

> last part of turncoat: "Coat." Coats protect from the elements

covering, protecting and providing warmth

> Coats provide warmth, covering, etc.

Comment: Maybe the first line is to establish that you are guessing one word (which "turncoat" is.)

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to try

> EXACT.

*I should begin by saying I am a word*

> This doesn't tell us any more than the [word](/questions/tagged/word) tag.

*In the beginning I followed established conventions*

> Take the beginning of the phrase "established conventions": the letter **E**.

*After that I decided that was not for me*

> After you've done something and then decided it wasn't for you, you're an **ex**-doer of that thing. So let's add an **X** to our word.

*So I decided to oppose everything that came after me*

> Not sure about this line. Maybe take the first letters of the words "came after" give CA, which reverse ("oppose") to **AC**.

*In the end I decided not to oppose, but to protect*

> The "end" of this line is the letter **T**.

Putting all this together, we get the answer I said at the start ... which also fits the title pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

How about this word?

> non-antitrust

Beginning - following established conventions.

> 'Non-' is a common convention / structure to signify the opposite of what comes next.

Oppose everything that came after me:

> 'Anti-x' usually means to oppose 'x' (with apologies to AntiX if necessary).

End: not oppose, to protect, cover, provide warmth

> 'Trust' has the flavour of all the above.

Comment: Nice. But it isnt muy word.

Answer (score 0):

Are you?

> person

I should begin by saying I am a word

> "person" is a word (sorry for stating the obvious lol)

In the beginning I followed established conventions

> the original plural form of "person" was "persons"

After that I decided that was not for me

> "people" is commonly the accepted plural form of "person" now, subjectively

So I decided to oppose everything that came after me

> persons came after (tried to change the use) of the word(s) "person", "persons", "people"

In the end I decided not to oppose, but to protect
covering, protecting and providing warmth

> people have all of these capabilities